# Asp.net web form model binding "Item" and "BindItem" same time to 1 control's multiple attributes/properties

Tags: asp.net, webforms, model-binding

I am using strongly typed  with a Gridview,

This will work (1 BindItem)

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="<%# BindItem.Price %>" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

This will work (1 Item)

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="" Enabled="<%# Item.Price==5 %>" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

This  will not work (1 BindItem and 1 Item)

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="<%# BindItem.Price %>" Enabled="<%# Item.Price==5 %>" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

> CS0103: The name 'Item' does not exist in the current context

It seems once we use BindItem in 1 place, we can't use binding in with this control again.

I know I can wrap the textbox with a panel to control the "Enabled" property as a fix

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is correct, but have you tried `<%= Item.Price == 5 %>`? This will output the result of the expression in the Enabled spot.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `Item.Price==5` with `BindItem.Price==5`.